# OpenGL Buffer Object internal workings?

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I've started to use Pixel Buffer Objects and while I understand how to use them and the gist of what they're doing, I really don't know what's going on under the hood. I'm aware that the OpenGL spec allows for leeway in regards to the exact implementation, but that's still beyond me.

So far as I understand, the Buffer Object typically resides server side in GRAM; though this apparently may vary depending on *target* and *usage*. This makes perfect sense as this would be why OpenGL calls on the BOs would operate so fast. But in what such instances would it reside in AGP or system memory? (side question: does PCI-e have an equivalent of AGP memory?)

Also, `glMapBuffers()` returns a pointer to a block of memory of the BO so the data may be read/written/changed. But how is this done? The manipulations are taking place client side, so the data still has to go from server to client some how. If it is, how is is better than `glReadPixels()`?
PBOs are obviously better than `glReadPixels()` as is obvious by the performance difference, I just don't understand how.

I haven't used FBOs yet, but I've heard they're better to use. Is this true? if so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you in what memory the buffer object will be allocated. Actually you mostly answered that question yourself, so you can hope that a good driver will actually do it this way.

glMapBuffer can be implemented the same way as memory mapped files. Remember the difference between physical memory and virtual address space: when you write to a memory location, the address is mapped through a page table to a physical location. If the required page is marked as swapped out an interrupt occurs and the system loads the required page from the swap to the RAM. This mechanism can be used to map files and other resources (like GPU memory) to your process's virtual address space. When you call glMapBuffer, the system allocates some address range (not memory, just addresses) and prepares the relevant entries in page table. When you try to read/write to these addresses the system loads/sends it to the GPU. Of course this would be slow, so some buffering is done on the way.

If you constantly transfer data between CPU and GPU, I doubt that PBOs will be faster. They are faster when you make many manipulations on the GPU (like load from frame buffer, change a few texels with CPU and use it as a texture again on the GPU). Well, they can be faster in case of integrated graphics processor or AGP memory, because in that case glMapBuffer can map the addresses directly to the physical memory, effectively eliminating one copy operation.

Are FBOs better? For what? They are better when you need to render to texture. That's again because they eliminate one data copy operation.

Comment: so if I make a call to glMapBuffer() the pointer it returns may be to a portion of my processes virtual address space that maps to GRAM?

Comment: @jay.lee: Yes from your point of view. No in the sense that it may not be a direct access (unless GRAM is in the RAM). I don't know if it's possible to map the PCI bus directly to your memory. I'm not a low-level guy. If not then it must go through additional buffer.